# Why wont the cultists spawn TERRARIA(mobile 1.4)

Tags: terraria-mobile

I created a world using the drunk world seed (for fun), found the dead living tree, dug down (for the dungeon), defeated the dungeon guardian, defeated golem, then used a celestial sigil crafted in another world to try out the Moon Lord fight for fun. I was in Master mode and DEFINITELY wasn't prepared, so I died. I went to the dungeon to kill the Lunatic Cultist and summon the pillars to try again, but nothing was there. I killed the golem again, still nothing. I did this about 4 times before I figured if that was the problem it would have already corrected itself.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't entered hardmode by killing the Wall of Flesh. That's usually the trigger for Lunatic Cultist, considering Golem is dead.

You may also need to kill the mechanical bosses and Plantera; Terraria's boss spawn logic is pretty rigid post-hardmode.

Comment: How do you kill Golem and use a Sigil if it's not in hardmode?

Comment: As far as I know, neither of them actually require hardmode to trigger. The trigger for golem is to get a Lihzahrd Power Cell, which you shouldn't be able to access without killing Plantera, so they don't bother with remaining logic. Same for Moon Lord, since the trigger is killing the pillars, and those don't spawn until the Cultist is killed, and the **cultist** has all the spawn logic.

Comment: Look's like the Sigil's requirement is that Golem has been killed, not that it's hardmode.

Comment: @OrangeDog Huh. Doesn't change the answer, though; you still need to be in hardmode to get the cultist.

Answer (score 0):

If the cultists aren't spawning, try defeating the Wall of Flesh. If that doesn't work, kill the mechanical bosses and Plantera. If they still aren't spawning, try defeating the Golem again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).